# Identify optional elements in XSD in c# once imported with CodeDom

Tags: c#, .net, xsd

I've analysed an XSD document inside which are some optional elements.
Within the produced C# code I find every int, decimal, datetime,... elements with an additional field xxxFieldSpecified. I understand this is for types not supporting null so the framework can know whether or not the element has been set and be used.
Is there however, a way to identify these fields when generating the class so I can automatically add a reference to this additional field when setting the field (using its property) instead of having to set the additional field all the time when setting the property, marking the property as set.

Also, when analysing the types inside a XmlShemaSet we know whether an element is an array (ArrayRank != 0). However, ArrayRank is always either 0 or 1 though sometimes the element is a multidimentional array, and ArrayRank should say 2 for instance... 
Is tehre a way to identify multidimentional arrays produced using ArrayRank or any other property or field ?

Answer (score 0):

For question 1 (optional elements) I found a way by when I find a property I check the list of fields looking for the propertyname+"FieldSpecified".

```
CodeMemberProperty m = (CodeMemberProperty)member;
if (m.HasSet)
    {
    // check if optional search for <name>FieldSpecified field
    bool optional = false;
    foreach (CodeTypeMember mtb in codeType.Members)
        if (mtb is CodeMemberField)
            if (optional = (0 == string.Compare(m.Name + "FieldSpecified", mtb.Name, true)))
                break;
    // if optional update setting flag when the property is set
    if (optional)
        {
        // set ...FieldSpecified when setting the property
        CodeAssignStatement cas = new CodeAssignStatement(new CodeFieldReferenceExpression(new CodeThisReferenceExpression(), m.Name + "FieldSpecified"), new CodePrimitiveExpression(true));
        m.SetStatements.Add(cas);
        }
    }
```

Probably not very smart but efficient.
If anybody has another way to do it...

Second question (multidimentional arrays) remains open.